# centering an image on only small screens with twitter bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have an image I'm trying to center in the middle of a div, but only on xs screens using twitter bootstrap.

On small and larger screens the layout looks like this:

[image]

When it goes to an xs screen it looks like this:

[image]

When the text falls off the page on the xs screen I'd like to have the image centered.

My html for this div is this:

**HTML**

```
        <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1">
                    <div class="col-xl-4 col-md-5 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                        <div class="img">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xl-8 col-md-7 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                        <div class="info">  
                        </div>
                        <div class="icons">
                            <ul class="list-inline icon-list">
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

The img div is the one containing the image that I want to center on small screens.

I attempted the following CSS but it doesn't work:

**CSS**

```
.col-xs-12  > .img img {
display: block;
margin: 0, auto !important;
}
```

It's not clear to me why this isn't working.

Comment: Off topic, but is that a real product?!

Comment: Remove the comma from `margin`

Comment: @jurgemaister - Yes it is. [link](http://www.healthkismet.com/purple-dragon/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply `text-align` on the column of the div with class img. Call it with class `centered` for practical reasons

```
.centered {
    text-align:center;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/udwtavzh/2/

Comment: I add custom classes for my builds, in this case "xs-center". If it's a block level element I'd be applying the following:

    .xs-center { 
        margin:            0 auto;
    }


Loving the product branding!

Comment: I add centered class like you did but my image is always in center of the screen not only small screen.